# Mux multiple mp4-m4a files without ask to overwrite

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, batch-file

I try to mux multiple mp4 files (without audio) with m4a files located in same folder
Generic command is

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%~na.mp4" -i "%%~na.m4a" -c copy "%%~na.mp4"
```

But this is problematic because it ask me if I want overwrite. I have filenames like this to mux

```
Episode 1 [sometext].m4a
Episode 1 [sometext].mp4
Episode 2 [sometext].m4a
Episode 2 [sometext].mp4
Glory and Pain.m4a
Glory and Pain.mp4
Ghost in 2 episode.m4a
Ghost in 2 episode.mp4
```

Output that I expect should don't use same names or ask me to overwrite, but simply to add a "muxed" suffix

```
Episode 1 [sometext]_muxed.mp4
Episode 2 [sometext]_muxed.mp4
Glory and Pain_muxed.mp4
Ghost in 2 episode_muxed.mp4
```

any idea?

Comment: I'm no Windows batch specialist at all, but wouldn't `"%%~na[sometext].mp4"` simply do?

Comment: Add `-y` argument for overwriting without asking: `ffmpeg -y `...

Comment: @Rotem the problem with the current command is that the output file is the same than the input file, so he has to change that first. Maybe he did, but he didn't bother to give us some feedback...

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this ***[Automatically overwrite file if already exists with FFmpeg](https://write.corbpie.com/automatically-overwrite-file-if-already-exists-with-ffmpeg/)***

---

You can run this batch file :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title MUX mp4-m4a files with FFmpeg
Set MUX_Folder=%~dp0MUX_Folder
MkDir "%MUX_Folder%">nul 2>&1
@for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%~na.mp4" -i "%%~na.m4a" -c copy -y "%MUX_Folder%\%%~na_muxed.mp4"
Explorer "%MUX_Folder%"
```